# How is the variable sized JavaScript string a primitive type?

Tags: javascript, string, stack, primitive-types

From what I understand, the (basic) `string` type in JavaScript is a primitive type, meaning its variables are allocated on the stack.

I would have thought that for a type to be allocatable on the stack, it needed to have a fixed size -- something which presumably holds true for the other primitive types like `boolean`, `number`, etc.

Am I somehow wrong to assume that, or is some other internal magic used to make `string`s in JavaScript primitive types?

---

EDIT:
This gets more complicated when one considers that JavaScript is loosely typed. Which makes me wonder how *any* local variable can be allocated on the stack.... given that the size of what might be assigned to it during the course of a function is not fixed.

But I guess (a perhaps simplified) answer to this might be that all local variables could be assigned a fixed maximum size on the stack. Say this is 8 bytes which I think is the size of the `number` type, and should be large enough to accommodate all the other primitive types (except the `string`) as well as memory addresses (for when a local variable is assigned a reference type). But, surely strings cannot be limited to 8 bytes (or any size for that matter). Which makes me conclude that strings (even the primitive type ones) are not (cannot be) assigned on the stack. And hence the term "Primitive type" in JavaScript is used to mean a "basic/building block" type, rather than one which is necessarily allocated on the stack (contradicting what I have read in numerous sources including the book "Professional JavaScript..." by Nicholas Zakas).

Anyone have any other take or a pointer to a good source talking about this?

Answer (score 1):

A string is a both an object and a primitive.

When doing:

```
var s = "this is a string";
```

you actually do:

```
var s = new string("this is a string");
```

behind the curtains.

The first being a primitive array with characters, on which the second one refers.

Strings are immutable, meaning they can't be changed. If you try to change it (i.e. reverse it), you will create a new string primitive, on which the object reference will point to.

Comment: The first string is actually a primitive type while the second is a reference type which is a wrapper for the primitive string type.

Comment: Yeah, but that means my original question remains unanswered :)

Answer (score 0):

The storage used to represent variables in the Javascript interpreter need not look anything like a stack - it's implementation dependent.

Comment: Could you elaborate further please? According to what I have read, primitive types in JavaScript are distinguished from the reference types by the former being allocated on the stack (with a primitive variable actually containing the value it refers to), while the later are allocated on the heap (with a reference variable containing only the memory address where the value is actually stored, putting it simplistically, that is)

Comment: "stack" and "heap" are convenience representations for how _most_ architectures happen to handle variables in memory.  However not even the C standard requires that they actually exist.

Comment: But are you saying most JavaScript implementations do allocate primitive types on the stack (even if that is not required by the specification.) If so, my question holds?

Answer (score 0):

1. Strings aren't allocated on the stack
2. where a variable is allocated doesn't distinguish primitives from objects
3. Strings aren't primitives, they are of the class "string"

The difference between a primitive and a type is that types have methods and you can assign new properties to them:

```
var a = 1, b = {}, s = '';
a.foo = 1; // doesn't work, but no error either
b.foo = 1; // works
s.foo = 1; // doesn't work, but no error either

console.log(a.foo);
console.log(b.foo);
console.log(s.foo);
​
```

gives

```
undefined
1
undefined
```

So all in all, I'm not sure that using "primitive" makes sense in JavaScript since the line is blurred.

A string is a "value object" which means you can't change any of the properties. For example, when you replace characters in a string, you get a new string; the old string doesn't change.

Comment: All primitive types have corresponding reference types wrappers -
`new Number()`, `new String()`, `new Boolean()` etc.
When you call a method on a primitive string type, behind the scenes 1) a new String() instance is created 2) the method is called on it 3) and then the instance is destroyed.

Comment: Also, according to various sources, JavaScript has the following five primitive types:
Undefined, Null, Boolean, Number, and String.
(And though I have commonly found them written this way, I think these should be written starting with lowercase letters to distinguish them from the corresponding *reference* wrapper types.)

Finally, according to Professional JavaScript For Web Developers by Nicholas Zakas:
"Primitive values are simple pieces of data that are **stored in memory on the stack...**" (emphasis mine), contradicting your point 2.

Comment: Re quote from Nicholas Zakas: That's either not correct or an oversimplification. Also JavaScript doesn't create new strings when you call a method on a string. The method might *return* a new string instance but calling methods on anything in JavaScript doesn't create clones automatically.

Comment: Hmm, the 3-step process I mentioned is paraphrased from the same text by Nicholas Zakas text.. so I would to believe it, unless I am pointed to a more authoritative source contradicting it.
Also, regarding your point that being able to "call methods" makes a variable an object/reference type, test the following on a JS console:
var n = 5;
n.toString() (and a bunch of other methods that show up)
I would contend it's the same mechanism whereby these methods are actually being called on a wrapper Number type instance that gets created (and deleted) on the fly.
In any case, surely n is primitive?

Comment: While I remain unsure about some of what you wrote, I now sort of get it (see the edit in my original post) when you say that using the word "primitive" type in JS might not make sense (or at least that its used in a sense different from Java/C# type languages.)
However just to confirm, even when you say that a string is a "value object", it still must be true that after`var s = "hello"`, `s` doesn't contain the *value* of the string, but only a reference to it, right?

Comment: In Java, a primitive is something that has no methods. All operations are implements in the language compiler itself; there is no way to influence it at runtime. I'm really uneasy with the term "primitive" in JavaScript; `1` is a literal (not a primitive), the `Number` type has some properties of a primitive but it allows method calls. So maybe it's convenience.

Comment: "Value object" refers to objects that can't change their value - they behave like primitives but you need OO to create them (i.e. `new`).